# Show $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int u_n \, d\mu = \int u \, d\mu$ for a sequence $(u_n)$ of non-negative functions

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(u_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of positive, measurable functions in $\mathcal{M}^+(\mathcal{A})$, let $u\in\mathcal{M}^+(\mathcal{A})$, and assume the following:

- $u_n(x)\rightarrow u(x)\ \forall x \in X$
- $u_n\leq u \ \forall n$.

Prove that

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int u_n\ d\mu = \int u\ d\mu.$

I'd appreciate some help here.

I found the following corollary in my book:

$\int u \ \  d\mu = \lim_{j\rightarrow \infty} \int f_j\  d\mu $

which holds for every increasing sequence $(f_j)_{j\in\mathbb{N}}\subset \varepsilon^+$ with $\lim_{j\rightarrow \infty}f_j=u$.

Can I argue that $(u_n)$ is an increasing sequence and then simply refer to the corollary? It is not stated that $(u_n)$ is in $\varepsilon^+$, som I'm not sure if I'm on the right track.

Comment: What is $\varepsilon^+$? And it's not given that $(u_n)$ is a monotonic sequence. But you can obtain a monotonic sequence from it. Pertinent keywords are Fatou and $\liminf$.

Comment: $\varepsilon^+$ is the set of positive simple functions. And thanks a lot, I'll go look those up straightaway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. By the monotonicity of the integral, $$\int u_n \, d\mu \leq \int u \, d\mu$$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. This implies $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \int u_n \, d\mu \leq \int u \, d\mu. \tag{1}$$
2. By assumption, $u_n$ is non-negative. Using Fatou's lemma and $$\int u \, d\mu = \int \liminf_{n \to \infty} u_n \, d\mu$$ show that $$\int u \, d\mu \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \int u_n \, d\mu. \tag{2}$$
3. Combine $(1)$ and $(2)$ to show $$\int u \, d\mu = \liminf_{n \to \infty} \int u_n \, d\mu = \limsup_{n \to \infty} \int u_n \, d\mu.$$ Conclude.

Comment: Thanks! In (2), what identity are you referring to? I couldn't find it in my book

Comment: @user275969 By "identity" I mean the next line, i.e. $$\int u \, d\mu = \int \liminf_n u_n \, d\mu.$$

Comment: I thought so, I'm just wondering where it comes from? I'm sorry if it should be obvious

Comment: @user275969 By assumption, $u_n(x) \to u(x)$. So what do you know about $$\liminf_{n \to \infty} u_n(x)$$ ...?

Comment: Oh of course, thanks!

Comment: @user275969 You are welcome.