# Does $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int u_n\ d\mu = \int u\ d\mu$ still hold without non-negativity

Tags: measure-theory

My question is related to this post:
[Show $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int u_n \, d\mu = \int u \, d\mu$ for a sequence $(u_n)$ of non-negative functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1460032/show-lim-n-to-infty-int-u-n-d-mu-int-u-d-mu-for-a-sequence-u)

in which it was proved that 
$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int u_n\ d\mu = \int u\ d\mu.$

I was wondering if this result would still hold, if non-negativity wasn't guaranteed for $(u_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ and $u(x)$?
My guess is no, since Fatou's lemma would be invalid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it does not hold. Consider for example the sequence
$$
u_n = - 1_{(n,n+1)}.
$$

Then $u_n \leq 0$ and $u_n \to 0 =:u$ pointwise, but $\int u_n \, dx = -1 \not\to 0=\int u \, dx$.

One can certainly modify the assumptions slightly to achieve a positive result. Assume for example that $u_n \geq v$ for all $n$ and some integrable function $v$. Then just consider the modified sequence $v_n := u_n -v \geq 0$. We have $v_n \to u-v$ pointwise and $v_n \leq u-v$, so that the result from the original question yields
$$
\int u_n -v \, dx =\int v_n \, dx \to \int u-v \, dx,
$$
so that we can add $\int v \, dx$ to both sides to achieve the desired convergence.

Answer (score 0):

Fatous's lemma in its full form has lim sup involved. What's the limit of $\chi_{(-1)^n}$? It doesn't exist! But the measure of these two functions is the same so the LHS of this equation does hold.